# How to properly push object to data from Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

I tried to push some data received from Apollo Client,

```
    data.push({ key: `blank-${numberOfElementsLastRow}`, empty: true 
  return data; )}
```

But this gives me an error,  Attempted to assign to readonly property.
My question is How I can properly use data.push to the data getting from Apollo Client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data from Apollo client is immutable (may not be altered).  You would need to create a clone of the data, either by creating a deep clone (using something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep)) or by spreading the properties of your object across a new object:

```
const { data , loading, error, fetchMore } = useQuery(GET_USERS,{
  variables: { cursor:  "" },
})

const mutableUsers = data.users.map(_ => {..._}); // Not sure this will work, can't remember how deep the immutability runs on these objects
```

As an aside, you are not supposed to modify data returned from an Apollo query, as this will mess up the local cache (hence the objects being immutable to begin with).  For reference:  https://www.apollographql.com/blog/previewing-the-apollo-client-3-cache-565fadd6a01e

> InMemoryCache results are frozen/immutable